# How can I use Line to get just one array from a C# dataset?

Tags: c#

I have this C# code:

```
    public static List<ExcelDataModel> ExcelDataList(DataSet ds)
    {
        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
```

What I would like to do is to just get the Database called Phrase. So I tried something like this:

```
    DataTable dtphrase = ds.Tables.where(x => x.Tables == "Phrase").FirstOrDefault();
```

I am trying with this where clause but it doesn't recognise me adding a where after ds.Tables.

[image]

Comment: So basically you want to access data table which contains data from "Phrase" table?

Comment: Still trying to attach.  Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables["Phrase"];
```

Comment: Thanks,  this worked although now I have another problem.  I will ask another question shortly.

Comment: Glad it helped you. please accept the answer if it solved your described problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try like this:

```
            ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "workers");
            datagrdvPracownicy.DataSource = ds.Tables["workers"];
```